# Run screen command with variable & tick through cron (cron run .sh)

Tags: cron, gnu-screen

I run screen command through cron, where the codes is in `lorem.sh` files.

This is cron codes: `* * * * * cd /home/z; ./lorem.sh`

Inside `lorem.sh`:

```
screen -S screenname -X stuff $'\033[B'
sleep 1 && screen -S screenname -X stuff 2
sleep 1 && screen -S screenname -X stuff "lorem ipsum dolor"
sleep 1 && screen -S screenname -X stuff $'\n'
```

Above `lorem.sh` codes: First line is "Arrow down", and forth line is "Enter"

When running `lorem.sh` through cron, only second & third line working.

Above `lorem.sh` works fine if run from terminal by typing `./lorem.sh` but not working from cron

Comment: `cron` may be using `/bin/sh` as your shell instead of your usual shell (which is likely `bash`), and on some systems `/bin/sh` doesn't know about '$' in front of strings. If you edit `lorem.sh` to have `#!/bin/bash` as its first line, does it work?

Comment: It working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most versions of `cron` run commands using `/bin/sh` by default, and if the commands run any shell scripts (that don't have a `#!` line to force use of a specific shell), `/bin/sh` will be used to run them, too.

On some systems, `/bin/sh` is `dash`, a shell that doesn't understand the [ANSI-C quoting convention](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) used by `bash` and other shells. So your `$'\n'` string is probably getting interpreted as the 3-character string `$\n`.

Most versions of `cron` will let you specify a shell to run your commands. You can have it use `bash` by editing your crontab to add a line

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

that comes before any lines that schedule jobs.

Alternatively, you can make `lorem.sh` always use `bash` by adding

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as its first line.